# how to Access value of a script from another script and modify in unity#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces, public

hi want to access the public vector value NewMax in another script and modify the x value

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

namespace Lean.Common
{
    /// <summary>This component allows you to convert 1, 2, or 3 values from one range to another. For example, an angle in the range of -90..90 could be converted to 0..1. This is done by calling one of the <b>SetX/Y/Z</b> methods, and then sending it out using the <b>OnValueX/Y/Z</b> events.</summary>
    [HelpURL(LeanHelper.PlusHelpUrlPrefix + "LeanRemapValue")]
    [AddComponentMenu(LeanHelper.ComponentPathPrefix + "Remap Value")]
    public class LeanRemapValue : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [System.Serializable] public class FloatEvent : UnityEvent<float> {}
        [System.Serializable] public class Vector2Event : UnityEvent<Vector2> {}
        [System.Serializable] public class Vector3Event : UnityEvent<Vector3> {}

        

        /// <summary>The range of the input values.</summary>
        public Vector3 OldMin { set { oldMin = value; } get { return oldMin; } } [SerializeField] private Vector3 oldMin;

        /// <summary>The range of the input values.</summary>
        public Vector3 OldMax { set { oldMax = value; } get { return oldMax; } } [SerializeField] private Vector3 oldMax = Vector3.one;

        /// <summary>The range of the output values.</summary>
        public Vector3 NewMin { set { newMin = value; } get { return newMin; } } [SerializeField] private Vector3 newMin;

        /// <summary>The range of the output values.</summary>
        public Vector3 NewMax { set { newMax = value; } get { return newMax; } } [SerializeField] private Vector3 newMax = Vector3.one;
    }
}
```

when I tried this from another script

```
public void voltageFlowCheck() //meter
    {    Lean.Common.LeanRemapValue.NewMax.x=2;
         Amount_of_Voltage_Passing_out = Lean.Common.LeanFormatString.Qapp_value; 
               }
```

I got the following error :-

> Vector3 Lean.Common.LeanRemapValue.NewMax { get; set; } The range of
> the output values.
>
> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
> property 'LeanRemapValue.NewMax' [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0120)

how can I fix this and get the value? And is there any way to call it using gameobject.GetComonent<>()

Comment: Your class/variables are not static. So you must reference an instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to get the GameObject that the LeanRemapValue class is attached to, and then with
`.GetComponent().NewsMax you get the value and can modify it.

You can get the GameObject in the editor or with the `GameObject.Find()` method.

If a script inherits from MonoBehaviour it has to be attached to a GameObject and then the script acts as a component.      .